# IBM tivoli identity manager

Tags: websphere-7

I am new to Tivoli identity manager and need to setup the same for an existing project. Please let me know how to configure tivoli identity manager for web service security management in Websphere 7.0.0.0 ? Basically i am looking for trust chain and STS setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much broader category to answer. You can simply get into some PDF to help you out with TIM configuration. There are a lot of them available online.

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer to Trust Chains and STS, you are actually asking about the wrong product. What you want to look into is Tivoli Federated Identity Manager. A good place to start is http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZSXU/welcome